# Mysql table formatting with Ruby mysql gem

Tags: mysql, ruby, formatting

Mysql by default prints table results in mysql table formatting

```
+----+----------+-------------+
| id | name     | is_override |
+----+----------+-------------+
|  1 | Combined |           0 |
|  2 | Standard |           0 |
+----+----------+-------------+
```

When calling mysql from the unix shell this table formatting is not preserved, but it's easy to request it via the -t option

```
mysql -t my_schema < my_query_file.sql
```

When using Ruby, I'm using the mysql gem to return results. Since the gem returns data as hashes, there's no option to preserve table formatting. However, is there any way I can easily print a hash/data with that formatting? Without having to calculate spacing and such?

```
db = Mysql.new(my_database, my_username, my_password, my_schema)
result = db.query("select * from my_table")
result.each_hash { |h|
   # Print row. Any way to print it with formatting here?
   puts h 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some gems and codes:

- https://rubygems.org/gems/datagrid
- http://rubygems.org/gems/text-table
- https://github.com/visionmedia/terminal-table
- https://github.com/geemus/formatador
- https://github.com/wbailey/command_line_reporter
- https://github.com/arches/table_print
- http://johnallen.us/?p=347

I have not tried any of them.

Comment: The 2nd option (text-table) is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!